# Placing Object Around a Rotating point

Tags: c++, math, positioning

I have two objects, `object1` and `object2`. `object1` rotates around its center and `object2` will be positioned around it. The problem is getting the positioning of `object2` correct; it's not 100% accurate.

Here is my code:

```
angle = atan2(
    cEnemy->position.y - (float) position.y,
    cEnemy->position.x - (float) position.x) / 3.14159265f * 180);
```

*`position.x` and `position.y` represent `object1`'s position.*

That's my angle there for which `object1` uses to rotate with. Now I'm stuck on how to go about positioning `object2`.

I presume that I need to first get the central points of `object1` which equal:

```
object2.x = (position.x + widthOfObject1 / 2);
object2.y = (position.y + heightOfObject1 / 2);
```

But then I'm just unsure about what to-do with the angle that `object1` will face, and how to use that to position `object2` correctly. I am pretty sure that I have to use `sin` or `cos` here, but I am unsure were. My idea is to position `object2` so that not matter what angle it's at, `object2` will also be in-front of `object1` by a small margin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well I was about to until the last paragraph. "position object2 so that not matter what angle it's at, object2 will also be in-front of object1 by a small margin" ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want to do is object2 is at a fixed distance **D** from Position **P** and you want to rotate it around P by angle **A**

So a unit vector along **A** is `[ cos(A) , sin(A) ]`

so a vector along **A** of magnitude **D** is   `[ D cos(A) , D sin(A) ]`

So the position of object 2 should be

```
object2.x = object1.x + D * cos(A)
object2.y = object1.y + D * sin(A)
```